# how to limit size of an image in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I am new to symfony and php. By reading the symfony documentation I uploaded an image successfully. But now I am struggling to limit the size of of an image. I tried by using annotations, but it's not working. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance. Here is my code.

```
/**
 * @Assert\Image(
 *     minWidth = 100,
 *     maxWidth = 400,
 *     minHeight = 100,
 *     maxHeight = 400,
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload valid image"
 * )
 */

 public $file;



public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}
```

Comment: no error messages..but its upload any size images...

Comment: I'm not sure if that new line between your annotation and the `$file` property has any significance - try removing that. Also since you have a getter and setter method, you may want to make the `$file` property `protected` instead of `public`.

Comment: i tried by changed $file to protected and removed the space.But no change in the result.

Comment: Show your controller method.

Answer (score -1):

Can you remove the empty line between the docblock and the `$file` property?